# ansible ec2 instance creation doesnt wait for public-ip to be assigned

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am trying to launch an ec2 instance with ansible playbook.

It is able to launch an instance but then. It doesnt wait until the public-ip is assigned to the vm.

```
- name: Start an instance with a public IP address
  amazon.aws.ec2_instance:
    name: "{{ ansible_test_instance_name }}"
    key_name: "{{ ansible_keypair_name }}"
    vpc_subnet_id: "{{ ansible_test_subnet }}"
    region: "{{ region }}"
    aws_access_key: "{{ lookup('env', 'aws_access_key_id') }}"
    aws_secret_key: "{{ lookup('env', 'aws_secret_access_key') }}"    
    instance_type: "{{ ansible_test_instance_type }}"
    security_group: "{{ ansible_security_group_name }}"
    wait: true
    wait_timeout: 20
    count: 1
    network:
      assign_public_ip: true
    image_id: "{{ ansible_test_image }}"
    tags:
      Environment: Testing
  register: ec2

- name: Add the newly created EC2 instance(s) to host group
  lineinfile: dest={{ hostpath }}
              regexp={{ item.public_ip }} 
              insertafter="[local]" 
              line="{{ item.public_ip }} {{hoststring}}"
              state=present
  with_items: "{{ec2.instances}}"
```

When I run this I get

```
TASK [ec2 : Add the newly created EC2 instance(s) to host group] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /app/infra/roles/ec2/tasks/ec2.yml:21
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'public_ip'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/app/infra/roles/ec2/tasks/ec2.yml': line 21, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: Add the newly created EC2 instance(s) to host group\n  ^ here\n"
}
```

register variable output

```
            "private_ip_address": "172.31.3.218",
            "product_codes": [],
            "public_dns_name": "",
            "root_device_name": "/dev/sda1",
            "root_device_type": "ebs",
            "security_groups": [
                {
                    "group_id": "sg-0f3c9e97c545d3447",
                    "group_name": "ansible_test_sg"
                }
```

Though we kept wait it doesn't wait until the public-ip is assigned to the VM i guess. I see a public_ip on aws console as well.
What am i missing? can anyone help?
Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no `public_ip` key in the returned values, indeed, there is a [`public_ip_address`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/amazon/aws/ec2_instance_module.html#return-instances/public_ip_address), tough.

Comment: Yea i tried with public_ip_address as well.  and i get the same error 
```
task path: /app/infra/roles/ec2/tasks/ec2.yml:21
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'public_ip_address'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/app/infra/roles/ec2/tasks/ec2.yml': line 21, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: Add the newly created EC2 instance(s) to host group\n  ^ here\n"
} ```

Answer (score 0):

Came with another work around. I did the following.

```
- name: Pause for 30 seconds to start instance
  ansible.builtin.pause:
    seconds: 30

- name: Check if instance is available
  amazon.aws.ec2_instance_info:
    region: "{{ region }}"
    aws_access_key: "{{ lookup('env', 'aws_access_key_id') }}"
    aws_secret_key: "{{ lookup('env', 'aws_secret_access_key') }}"
    instance_ids: "{{ ec2.instance_ids }}"
  register: ec2_node_info

- name: Wait for SSH to come up
  local_action: wait_for
                host={{ item.public_ip_address }}
                port=22
                state=started
  with_items: "{{ec2_node_info.instances}}"
```

and got it to work

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue, and adding `state: running` solved the issue.

```
    - name: Create ephemeral EC2 instance(s)
  ec2_instance:
    profile: "{{ item.aws_profile | default(omit) }}"
    region: "{{ item.region | default(omit) }}"
    filters: "{{ platform_filters }}"
    instance_type: "{{ item.instance_type }}"
    image_id: "{{ platform_image_id }}"
    vpc_subnet_id: "{{ item.vpc_subnet_id }}"
    security_groups: "{{ platform_security_groups }}"
    network:
      assign_public_ip: "{{ item.assign_public_ip }}"
    volumes: "{{ item.volumes }}"
    key_name: "{{ (item.key_inject_method == 'ec2') | ternary(item.key_name, omit) }}"
    tags: "{{ platform_tags }}"
    user_data: "{{ platform_user_data }}"
    wait: true
    state: running
```